# Find the distance of the solution of a system of differential equations with the $0$ solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, normed-spaces

I am given the system of ODE
$$x'(t)=x(x^2 +y^2)-x$$
$$y'(t)=y(x^2+y^2)-y$$
for $t \geq 0$

I want to find $$d(t)=\| v(t)-v_0 (t) \|$$ without solving the system.

where $v(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ is a solution to the system and $v_0=(0,0)$ is the zero solution
($\| \cdot \|$ is the euclidean norm).

My attempt, by multiplying the first equation by $x$ and the second by $y$, adding them together and switching to polar coordinates I ended up with
$$r'=r^4-r^2$$
Now, I Know that $$d(t)=r$$ so if I solve $$r'=r^4-r^2$$ I will get the solution, but the problem says that I should find $d(t)$ without solving the system and this is where I am stuck.

How can I find $d(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x(x^2 +y^2-1)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=y(x^2+y^2-1)$$
Trivial solution : $x(t)=y(t)=0.$

Solving in the case $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$ :
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(x^2 +y^2-1)}{x(x^2 +y^2-1)}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y}{x}$$
$$y=c_1x$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x(x^2 +(c_1x)^2-1)=x^3+(c_1^2-1)x$$
This ODE is separable. The solution is :
$$x(t)=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{c_1^2+1+c_2e^{2t}}}$$
$$y(t)=\pm\frac{c_1}{\sqrt{c_1^2+1+c_2e^{2t}}}$$
This general solution includes the trivial solution $x=y=0$ corresponding to the particular case $c_2=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that your left side is incomplete. It is
$$
rr'=xx'+yy'=r^4-r^2
$$
This now is a Bernoulli equation for $r$ or $u=r^2$, or at the basis of both, a linear equation in $v=r^{-2}-1$.
$$
r(t)^{-2}-1=(r_0^{-2}-1)e^{2t}
\implies
r(t)=\frac{r_0}{\sqrt{r_0^2+(1-r_0^2)e^{2t}}}
=\frac{r_0e^{-t}}{\sqrt{1-r_0^2(1-e^{-2t})}}
$$

Comment: And this is also a separable ODE.

Comment: Yes, as any Bernoulli or Ricatti DE with constant coefficients.